# Vanguard: Targeted Retirement Mutual Funds vs Targeted Retirement Trusts

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, retirement, retirement-plan

I have two different 401(k) accounts and each hold a Vanguard "Targeted Retirement 2040" instrument. I had assumed they were the same, but I just realized that the two accounts actually hold different instruments.

One is the [Vanguard Target Retirement 2040 Fund (VFORX)](https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/mutual-funds/profile/vforx).

The other is the [Vanguard Target Retirement 2040 Trust Select (1680)](https://institutional.vanguard.com/investments/product-details/fund/1680).

It appears that the 1680's returns are *very slightly* higher than the VFORX's returns.

I am unfamiliar with the terminology of "Trust Select" vs simply "Fund". Is it simply a different mix of assets, or does it reflect some kind of organizational difference?

Can someone explain the differences between these two?

Comment: Trusts are the New Thing in the 401(k) world.  Their sole purpose is to confuse worker bees by not letting us Google share prices.

Comment: @RonJohn Ha, I noticed that :)

Answer (score 2):

These trusts are usually custom offerings to specific 401k plans with slightly different costs, based off of the fund. You'll see that for VFORX Vanguard publish a specific expense ratio (0.08%), but for the trust they don't.